# Keystore not replaced by Google

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, android-keystore

**Please Note: This question is not about lost keystore.**

I signed an apk with a keystore and uploaded it as draft in Google playstore. Soon I realized that keystore was created with wrong information. Created a new keystore and signed the same apk again. Uploaded it again to playstore. Note that the apk was never published till now. After uploading for second time, published the app.

When I now try to upload an update, with new keystore, Google says fingerprint not matching. Sign with keystore that was used to sign the first version of app!

Question: **Why did Google not replace the keystore when I uploaded the app again signed with new keystore? Is this a known issue/bug?** I have dropped a mail to Google support but would appreciate if anyone reply. Has anyone encountered the same problem? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm sure you already know that you can just unpublish this app if it has just been published, make some minor change to your package ID, reset your version code, and publish again as a new app.  You can use the same name without any difficulties arising therefrom.  So it is an interesting question, but you do have an easy workaround.

Comment: Yes I know but I need to justify it to customer that is not my fault. Its Google's. I am not looking for a workaround now but a justification or bug reference from Google. Will let you know if I hear something from anywhere.

Comment: It does *sound* like a bug.  If they allowed you to upload a new version and publish it with your new license key, then they should be willing to update using that same key.  Have you deleted the original version that had the different key?

Comment: Yes Carl, we deleted the old keystore when Google accepted the new build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have something from Google. It's a bug. I am quoting what they replied on mail...

> It looks like your draft upload was affected by a known bug. Currently, updates to draft APKs will not replace the existing APK unless the version number is higher. We're working on improving the messaging around this behavior and apologize for the inconvenience. Because of this, it's as if APK2 with KEYTSTORE2 was never upload so you will need to use KEYSTORE1 for all app updates.

Finally it is clear that the app was never uploaded because its version and version code were same as previous and Google still said success. They should immediately add this simple check. I will have to take my app down and publish again :(

Hope this helps anyone who faced similar problem. If anyone still has a workaround/fix, do let me know.